# Color Management Books for Programmer

Tags: color, color-management, books

I would like to develop a color management library that converts images for display, handles color profiles, does color proofing etc.

So far I found this book:
[Colour Management: Understanding and Using ICC Profiles](http://www.bookdepository.com/Colour-Management-Phil-Green/9780470058251)

but it is concerned with ICC profiles and not much with color management in general.

Most books about color management seem to be written for photographers, designers and other "end users". Some contain few formulas, but nothing on which you can base your own color management software.

I understand some basics about color explained in digital image processing books, but color management is something more elaborate and I need to connect the dots.

I am basically looking for something like "Numerical Recipes in C" book, but for color management...

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen [Charles Poynton's Color and Gamma FAQs](http://www.poynton.com/Poynton-color.html)?

These probably won't cover all the information that you need for your project, but there you'll find good information (and formulas!) for color models and conversions between them.

Comment: Thanks. Though the FAQs are outdated, there are references to useful books.

Comment: @Libor: By outdated do you mean just that they were written long ago, or that in addition to being written long ago they also have incorrect information that should be updated?

Comment: Just written long ago. The information in the FAQ is of course relevant today, but I look for primarily for something to make software of, which should incorporate things like ICC v4 or how to generate profile given measurements from a calibration target.